# Back button edit action

Tags: java, android

I have a splash screen and if I press the back button while the splash activity is running this activity is closed but the next activity after the splash (after 2 seconds) will be open. I would like to set the back button to close the splash activity but to open immediately the next activity or to close the whole application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the back-button with this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
       Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
       startActivity(i1);
    return;
```

This will take you to the next Activity when you pres the button. If you want to close the app try this:

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        return;
```

Comment: Thank you! First I thought I have to use Service Manager and that would be more complicated. Thank you again.

Comment: I found a new solution to start the new activity when the splash is onPause()